# Callback func as parameter in fetch

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fetch

I'm trying to pass in a callback function as an argument to fetch. But i dont know how to run the callback itself from index.js when fetch is complete in api.js.

index.js

```
import Api from './Api'
Api.post(callback)
```

Api.js

```
class Api {
  constructor () {}
  static post(callback) {
    let url 'dummy';
    let data = {
      id: 2
    }

    let request = new Request(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
      header: new Headers()
    })

    fetch(request)
      .then(function() {
        console.log(request);
      })
  }
}

export default Api;
```

Comment: Functions are always called with `()`. I.e. `callback()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* call your callback function in a `.then()`:

```js
class Api {
  static post (callback) {
    const request = /* ... */;
    fetch(request)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => callback(result)); // if you have a result
  }
}
```

... but why would you do that? Try to return a promise and work with that promise. This is what promises (and the fetch API) are about.

```js
class Api {
  static post () {
    const request = /* ... */;
    return fetch(request)
      .then(response => response.json());
  }
}
// usage: 
Api.post().then(callback);
```

Comment: It's a POST request though. I don't think they need to get any data back

Comment: Exactly. i dont get any data back, i just want to run a callback to be able o indicate that the post has been.. posted.

Comment: Do you meen "Api.post().then(callback({ do something  }));"   ?

Comment: No. `Api.post()` will return a promise which you can call `.then()` on. This is the way I would go, since it allows you to create a promise chain. Read more about promises on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or on many other great sites.

Comment: Ok. but how do i call the promise/callback in index.js ?

Comment: Export the API class and import it -- just as you already do -- and call it with `Api.post().then(function () { console.log('Request posted.'); });`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the callback in the `then` callback:

```
fetch(request)
  .then(function() {
    console.log(request);
    callback();
  })
```

Or chain it:

```
fetch(request)
  .then(function() {
    console.log(request);
  }).then(callback);
```